# select the unselected item from a react select

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a react select component like this:

```
const Select = ({ content, name, label, touched, onSelect, isValid, selected, dataSelector }) => {
    return (
        <select aria-label={name}
                        defaultValue={selected}
                        className={classnames('select select-box col-sm-2 col-xs-12',
                                                                    {'contains-error': touched && !isValid}
                            )}
                        id={name}
                        onChange={onSelect}
                        data-selector={dataSelector}
        >
            <option key="day" value=undefined>{label}</option>
            {content.map(({ value, text }) =>
                <option value={value} key={value}>{text}</option>
             )}
        </select>
    );
};
```

I am using `defaultValue` to set which item is from the `selected` prop.  But if `selected` is undefined, I want it to default to the first label.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Set a conditional `defaultValue` like

```
defaultValue={selected ? selected : content[0].value}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ternary operator` to put the condition in defaultValue, if selected prop in `undefined` then assign the value of first default label.

Instead of assigning `undefined` to first option assign some default value like 1 or -1 etc.

Use this:

```
<select 
    aria-label={name}
    defaultValue={selected ? selected : '1'}
    className={classnames('select select-box col-sm-2 col-xs-12',                                                                   {'contains-error': touched && !isValid} )}
    id={name}
    onChange={onSelect}
    data-selector={dataSelector}
        >
            <option key="day" value='1'>{label}</option>
            ....
</select>
```